# Embedded Vue.js not gives a blank screen using WKWebView

Tags: ionic-framework, wkwebview

We are planning to make a part of our app in Ionic using Vue and we are planning to use the native WKWebView to display Ionic screens but it only shows a blank screen.

These are the other things that we have tried:

1 - Using another compiled vue project that we found working - able to make it display in our app

2 - Starter vue project - blank screen

I think that the webview was able to render index.html since inspecting shows that `<div id="app"></div>` was rendered but was not able to execute the Ionic scripts and since it is not giving us any errors with:

```
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("Provisional navigation failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        self.stopActivityIndicator()
    }
    
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("Provisional navigation failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        self.stopActivityIndicator()
    }
}
```

[image]

It looks like that it wasn't able to load the js files
[image]

Using another compiled vue project that we found, we were able to display it. Are we doing something wrong wth compiling our project?

```
    func navigateTo(url urlString: String) {
      guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html",
                             inDirectory:  "vue") else {
                             print("‍ Unable to load local html file")
                             return
    }
    
    print("‍ Ionic bundle path: \(filePath)")

    let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let directory = baseURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
    let fullURL = URL(string: urlString, relativeTo: baseURL)


    print("‍ Ionic URL: \(baseURL)")
    self.mWebKitView.stopLoading()
    self.mWebKitView.loadFileURL(baseURL, allowingReadAccessTo: directory)
}
```